# Understanding the proof: A spanning tree in $G$ implies a spanning tree in dual graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

The theorem I am reading is as follows:

> Suppose $G$ is a connected planar graph. Let $T$ be the set of edges in $G$ which form a spanning tree and let $T^*$ be the set of all edges which are duals of the edges not in $T$. Then the edges of $T^*$ form a spanning tree of $G^*$.

The proof that I want to understand (from [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821842625) book) proceeds by showing that $T^*$ is acyclic and then connected. What I have a doubt is in that $T^*$ is connected. The argument (slightly changed from the book) is as follows:

> We show that $T^*$ is connected. To prove this let $T^*=T_1\sqcup T_2$. Let $U$ be the union of regions in $G$ with capital in $T^*$. $U$ is not the whole plane (no point of $T_2$ belongs to it). Hence the boundary $B$ of $U$ is
>   non-empty. Now $B$ consists of certain edges of $T$, having a region
>   of $U$ on one side and a region not in $U$ on the other side.
>   Therefore there is no vertex of degree $1$ on the boundary, which is a
>   contradiction as that would mean that the boundary yields a cycle in
>   $T$. So $T^*$ is a spanning tree.

I don't understand what is $U$ and why $B$ will be the way he describes. What does the author mean by capital?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764566/spanning-trees-in-planar-dual-graph

Comment: @Aravind: My question is specific to this proof.

Comment: Okay, but I don't understand even the beginning of this proof. What are $T_1$ and $T_2$ or why consider such a partition?

Comment: @Aravind: I believe that $T_1,T_2$ are the components of the assumed disconnected $T^*$. Also I think $U$ is a union of the faces determined by $T_1$ but I am not sure.

Comment: @Shahab: What number has the problem in the book and on what page can it be found?

Comment: @Moritz: This is problem 5.23 in the book. It is on page 43. The solution is on page 291-292.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is fairly simple but badly put. We first assume $T^*$ is disconnected. The author denotes this by $T^*=T_1\sqcup T_2$, but should probably be better written as $T^*=\bigsqcup_i T_i$.

The next line is very badly worded, I think the author means that $U$ is the union of regions of $G$ that contain a particular $T_i$. This follows from the next line, which states that $U$ contains no regions which 'have capital' in some other $T_j$.

The remaining argument states that $U$ is not the whole plane, and so has either an inner boundary, or an outer boundary, or possibly both.

And because this boundary splits $U$ from $U'$ it must be a cycle, which is a contradiction with the premise that the original $T$ is a tree.

Comment: "And because this boundary splits $U$ from $U′$ it must be a cycle". Why is that?

Comment: this is what the author says. i can see it intuitively - the author is quite prolific and i am assuming he has some other evidence. don't shoot the messenger!