# Spanning trees of a plane graph and its dual

Tags: graph-theory, trees

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764566/spanning-trees-in-planar-dual-graph) is a proof of the following statement:

> Let $T$ be a spanning tree of a connected plane multigraph $G$ and $T^*$ be a subgraph of $G^*$ whose edges correspond to the edges of $G$ not in $T$. Then $T^*$ is a spanning tree of $G^*$.

I am curious about two parts:

First- they did not prove that $T^{*}$ is connected. The proof seems to be a simple and short, but I cannot find the essence of it. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483585/understanding-the-proof-a-spanning-tree-in-g-implies-a-spanning-tree-in-dual) is another proof containing that part, but as mentioned in the question, it is too hard to understand.

Second- what can we do about the opposite side?They proved 'If $T$ is a spanning tree of $G$ and $T^*$ is constructed in such a way, then $T^*$ is a spanning tree of $G^*$. But can we ensure 'If such constructed $T^*$ is a spanning tree of $G^*$, then $T$ is a spanning tree of $G$.'?

I guess that using 'the dual of a dual graph of connected plane graph is itself' makes it obvious, but I am not clear yet. Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(T^*) = V(T^*)-1$ + acyclicity implies connectedness, this is a standard result for trees. In fact, the three following definitions are equivalent :
$T^*$ is connected and acyclic
$T^*$ is connected and have $V(T^*)-1$ edges
$T^*$ is acyclic and have $V(T^*)-1$ edges

In fact, you just need to of the three properties to have a tree.

The proof of connectedness here is very similar to the acyclicity, if $T^*$ has more than one component, we can find a cycle around that component, which gives a cycle in $T$ (Hence the contradiction).

> the dual of a dual graph of connected plane graph is itself

This is true, except that $T^*$ is not the classic dual of $T$. There is a duality between $T$ and $T^*$ relatively to $G$ and $G^*$, but we need to prove it. This is relatively easy: The edges of the dual of $T^*$ are the edges of $G$, except those corresponding to an edge of $T^*$. As the edges of $T^*$ correspond to the edges of $G$ not in $T$, the remaining edges must be only the ones in $T$.

Comment: I reached the contradiction when I supposed there are at least two components in $T^*$ by the number of edges. Thanks a lot!

Comment: More generally we can set up a bijection between subsets $S$ of edges of $G$ and subsets $S^{*}$ of edges of $G^{*}$: $S^{*}$ consists of the edges of $G^{*}$ not crossed by an edge of $S$. Then $S$ is connected iff $S^{*}$ is acyclic (and vice-versa of course by applying duality twice).